# Is it possible to get a list of decorations I own in text format? PC version

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I started using some websites/apps to help me build a set, such as [MHW Wiki Db](https://mhw.wiki-db.com/sim/?hl=en), and it has a feature to import a list (a JSON actually) of decos I own so the website won't suggest using something I don't have...

Is there any way I can get a list of all the decos I own? I imagine that playing on PC, maybe there is one such file that stores this information so I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a utility on NexusMods expressly for this purpose, in fact. It's called Decorations Save Exporter and can be found here: https://www.nexusmods.com/monsterhunterworld/mods/3495.

Comment: I downloaded it, and it's pretty much what I needed. Thanks!